# What is the correct way of asking your professor if we are still having a meeting?

Tags: email, greetings

We had meetings every week on the same day before fall break. I am not sure if it's the same thing after the break as well. Is this the right way to ask the professor if we are still having a meeting?

- I wasn’t sure about our meeting so just wanted to make sure if we are still meeting today?

Comment: We don't do "general purpose proofreading" here. Is there anything *specific* you're unsure about, in relation to your sample text above? It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to repeat the subject noun ***I*** before ***just wanted***, if that's what you're concerned about. And your text is phrased as a *statement*, not a *question*, so it should end with an ordinary full stop rather than a question mark.

Comment: ...plus strictly speaking in English we "make sure of" ***facts***, not ***questions***, so you either *wanted to make sure [that] **we are still meeting***, or you *wanted to know **if / whether** we are meeting*. You shouldn't have "if" after "make sure", but in every context I can think of it's entirely optional whether to include the relativiser ***that*** between "make sure" and the assertion (statement of fact) that follows.

Comment: The "wasn't sure about our meeting" part is strictly unnecessary.

Comment: Also, please edit to make clear what you're concerned about. Do you want to know about grammatical correctness? (That's not always necessary for a casual email. Your sentence isn't grammatically valid, but in my opinion totally ok; as a professor I wouldn't find it odd at all.) Or is your question about what words to choose and what tone they convey?

Comment: @AndyBonner I was curious if it sounded odd or not. Thanks for all the comments. IT helped me get a general idea.

Comment: Is our weekly meeting still 'on' after the break?